# Illegal return statement when checking browser support

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm using the following code from and Ethan Marcotte book that checks if the browser supports some of the DOM features.

```
// Is this browser sufficiently modern to continue?
if ( !( "querySelector" in document
  && "addEventListener" in window
  && "getComputedStyle" in window) ) {
    return;
}
window.document.documentElement.className += " enhanced";

var nav = document.querySelector( ".nav ul" ),
navToggle = document.querySelector( ".nav .skip" );
if ( navToggle ) {
  navToggle.addEventListener( "click",   function( e ) {
    if ( nav.className == "open" ) {
      nav.className = "";
    } else {
    nav.className = "open";
    }
    e.preventDefault();
  }, false );
}
```

Developer tools is reporting the following error;

Uncaught SyntaxError: Illegal return statement

I've tried changing the return to false, but that didn't work. Basically it's supposed to add the enhanced class to the html tag if those DOM features are found. Wondered if anyone can help where i'm going wrong.

Thanks.

Comment: Put it in a function. Call the function.

Comment: You aren't showing all your code but I expect @RyanO'Hara is correct in that you don't have this block of code in a function, so, what would you be returning from?

Comment: hey. i have added the nav code underneath, but this was all of the javascript provided in the book. :/

Answer (score 2):

I propose you to insert all the code in the load function:

```js
window.onload = function () {
  if (!("querySelector" in document
        && "addEventListener" in window
        && "getComputedStyle" in window)) {
    return;
  }
  window.document.documentElement.className += " enhanced";

  var nav = document.querySelector(".nav ul"),
      navToggle = document.querySelector(".nav .skip");
  if (navToggle) {
    navToggle.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
      if (nav.className == "open") {
        nav.className = "close";
      } else {
        nav.className = "open";
      }
      e.preventDefault();
    }, false);
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked">
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li class="dropdown">
        <a class="skip dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Menu 1 <span class="caret"></span></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Submenu 1-1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Submenu 1-2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Submenu 1-3</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu 3</a></li>
</ul>
```